# Deleting all directories in a given folder in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell script to delete all the sub directories in a given directory. I know there is an easy approach for the same.
Like doing this

`find ./ -type d -exec rm -r {} \;`
but since I am learning shell scripting so I prefer to write a script for the same. Here is my approach

```
for i in `ls ./*`; do
if [ -d $i ];then
rm -r $i
fi
done
```

When I run this script this gives me following errors

> rm: cannot remove directory: `.'

after giving this error this stops.So what is the error in  my approach.As far as I understand blank names should create some problem. But this script has failed to go that far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ls ./* makes a list of all the files in each immediate subdir of . The -d then checks the name of the file but as if it was in . not the subdir it comes from.

For example if you had:

```
foo1/
  bar
foo2/
  baz
```

then ls ./* would make a list of bar and baz, as the ./* would match foo1 and foo2 and ls would then list the contents of each of those 2 directories.

The error message you are getting is probably because your ls has been aliased to be 'ls -a' which lists . and .. As the answer by Florin says, you can use ls -A ./* to avoid that issue.

If you just want to delete the directories in ., just do:

```
for i in `ls -A`; do if [ -d $i ]; then rm -r $i; fi; done
```

Comment: +1 for the observation that ls ./* would list what is in subdirectories.

Answer (score 3):

`.` and `..` should not appear in the output of `ls`.

However, you can test with

```
ls -A
```

(-A means 'almost all'

-a means 'all')

And: why you don't jus use `for i in 'ls'` ?

Answer (score 3):

[You shouldn't use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in this command. There's a very simple way to make sure you only iterate over directories:

```
for dir in */
do
    echo "$dir"
done
```

Comment: FYI, you can also do `for dir in /tmp/foo/*/; do ...`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ls command list links for the current folder and the parent folder. So you must test if your i variable is setted to '.' or '..'

```
if [ -d $i ] -a [ $i != '.' ] -a [ $i != '..' ]
then
rm -r $i
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

"`*/`" should match all subdirectories

Try something like this:

`rm -rf /path/to/mySubfolder/*/`